# How to add stored procedure to already created edmx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, edmx

I have already created a edmx from database and now i want to add one stored procedure in to it. so how can i add it in edmx without affecting previously created edmx? please tell me the steps.

Comment: Update Model From Database? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double click the edmx file.
2. Right Click and Update Model from database.
3. Select which stored procedures you need.
4. Click Finish.